# Почему не влезает последний блок на iPhone / iPad?

Tags: html, css, ios, iphone

```css
.overlay {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: fixed;
    overflow: auto;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    z-index: 1000;
}

.popup {
  width: 375px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content {
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  background: red;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay">
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="content">
      <p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
      <a href="#">RED BUTTON</>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Есть попап http://prntscr.com/lc6ipv , в самом низу есть большая красная кнопка до которой невозможно доскроллить.
Его оверлэй и сам попап имеют такие стили:

```
.overlay {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  z-index: 1000;
}

.popup {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**Почему я не могу доскроллить до этого блока? На десктопах все ок**

Comment: Покажите пример с html-кодом, который продемонстрирует то, до чего нельзя доскроллить

Comment: @andreymal добавил

Comment: Прикольно, доскроллить и правда не получается. Предположу, что айфон считает 100vh с учётом скрытой адресной строки, а при скроллинге адресная строка не скрывается, и в итоге высота не влезает в видимую область страницы

Comment: Если стоит задача растянуть оверлей на всю страницу, то можно использовать `top: 0; bottom: 0` вообще без указания height

Comment: @andreymal спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в `height: 100vh;` можете использовать `top:0; bottom:0` если вам необходимо сделать `overlay` на всю страницу.

Так же можете установить высоту `overlay` при помощи JavaScript. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/7678419) описано как получить правильный `viewport` и дальше просто применить полученное значение для `overlay`.

```
    var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
    document.querySelector('.overlay').style.height = h;
```

**P.S** Этот баг хорошо описан [тут](https://nicolas-hoizey.com/2015/02/viewport-height-is-taller-than-the-visible-part-of-the-document-in-some-mobile-browsers.html), статья на английском но благодаря картинкам все будет более чем понятно :)

Comment: спасибо, сейчас начну тестировать, пробовать!

Comment: Помогло добавление к `.overlay` `bottom: 0` , но ссылку обязательно сохраню! Спасибо!

Comment: p.s. и удаление 100vh *